# Error uploading docs, pdf, jpg using php

Tags: php, html, pdo

Please am trying to upload docs, .docx, .pdf, .jpg files using php but each time I click on the upload button, I get this message: "uploadedFile format not supported! uploaded".

Please where is the problem coming from? It is supposed to be either 'uploaded' or 'file format not supported'.

Thanks.

```
<?php
         require_once "include/db_handle.php";
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
         if (!empty($_FILES['_file']['name'])) {
        if ($_FILES['_file']['type'] == 'application/msword') {
            $upload_folder = "./file_doc/";
            $pic_name = time() . ".doc";
            $pic_path = $upload_folder . $pic_name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['_file']['tmp_name'], $pic_path);

            $upload = "INSERT INTO tfiles (name)  VALUES  ('$pic_name')";
            if ($db->query($upload)) {
            echo "uploaded";
            }   
        }
        if ($_FILES['_file']['type'] == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
            $upload_folder = "./file_doc/";
            $pic_name = time() . ".doc";
            $pic_path = $upload_folder . $pic_name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['_file']['tmp_name'], $pic_path);

            $upload = "INSERT INTO tfiles (name)  VALUES  ('$pic_name')";
            if ($db->query($upload)) {
            echo "uploaded";
            }   
        }
        if ($_FILES['_file']['type'] == 'application/pdf') {
            $upload_folder = "./file_doc/";
            $pic_name = time() . ".pdf";
            $pic_path = $upload_folder . $pic_name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['_file']['tmp_name'], $pic_path);

            $upload = "INSERT INTO tfiles (name)  VALUES  ('$pic_name')";
            if ($db->query($upload)) {
            echo "uploaded";
            }   
        }
        if ($_FILES['_file']['type'] == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation') {
            $upload_folder = "./file_doc/";
            $pic_name = time() . ".pptx";
            $pic_path = $upload_folder . $pic_name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['_file']['tmp_name'], $pic_path);

            $upload = "INSERT INTO tfiles (name)  VALUES  ('$pic_name')";
            if ($db->query($upload)) {
            echo "uploaded";
            }   
        }

        if ($_FILES['_file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg') {
            $upload_folder = "./profile_pix/";
            $pic_name = time() . ".jpg";
            $pic_path = $upload_folder . $pic_name;
            require_once "include/resize.php";
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['_file']['tmp_name'], $pic_path)) {
                $image = new Resize($pic_path);
                $image->resizeImage(180, 180, 'crop');
                $image->saveImage($pic_path);

                //thumbnail
                $image = new Resize($pic_path);
                $image->resizeImage(50, 50, 'crop');
                $image->saveImage($upload_folder . "thumb/" . $pic_name);
            }

            $upload = "INSERT INTO tfiles (name)  VALUES  ('$pic_name')";
            if ($db->query($upload)) {
            echo "uploaded";
            }   
        }

        else{
            echo "File format not supported!";        
            }
         }
    }
    ?>
```

HTML Form

```
  <p class="points" > Add Files</p>
     <form name="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name= "_file" />
          <input type= "submit" name="upload" value="upload"/>
     </form>
```

Comment: You've got multiple `if` statements in your code, as you check for each different type of file. But the final one has an `else` - if you're uploading an MS Word file, you go into the first `if` statement; but because it's not a JPG, it also goes into the `else` for that block of code.

Comment: One fix would be to use `elseif` statements. You might also want to look at using a `switch` - both will work in the same way, but I find `switch` is a little easier to maintain.